# How to convert nested maps of type Map[String, Map[String, Any]] to JSON in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, jackson, json4s, spray-json

I tried converting Map[String, Map[String, Any]] in Scala to JSON but since they have nested maps so unable to do it. Is there a way to do it? I tried looking at this [link](https://tech.mendix.com/scala/2014/09/28/scala-nested-maps-to-json/) but it converts everything to string and converts a list as "List(...)". Any ideas how to go about this? I am even fine with solutions of Map[String, Map[String, String]].

Comment: You can have a look at http://json4s.org/

Comment: Why do you have `Any`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I also saw that one can do compact(render(decompose(nestedMap))). Here I am talking about the netliftweb.json library

Answer (score 1):

You can use [play-json library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11). Then converting nested maps would look like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}

val nestedMap: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = Map("employees" -> Map("Paul" -> "developer", "Alice" -> "accountant"))
val json: JsValue = Json.toJson(nestedMap)
val compactJson: String = Json.stringify(json)

println(compactJson)
```

Output:

```
{"employees":{"Paul":"developer","Alice":"accountant"}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also saw that one can do compact(render(decompose(nestedMap))). Here I am talking about the netliftweb.json library.